# Equivalence between spin 1 Ising model and 3 Potts q state model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

How can I show that the spin 1 Ising model has the same symmetry as the 3 state Potts model?

I want to show that on the square lattice the spin-1 Ising model, described by the Hamiltonian $H_1$,

$$
 H_1=-J\sum_{<i,j>} s_i s_j  -K\sum_{<i,j>} s_i^2 s_j^2 -D\sum_{i} s_i^2
,$$

has the same symmetry as the three-state Potts model, described by the Hamiltonian $H_2$,

$$
 H_2= -J\sum_{<i,j>} \delta_{s_j,s_j},
$$

if $D+2(J+K)=0$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, I searched for my question but I didn't find anything unfortunatelly

Comment: Jila, you'd increase the chances of the question picking someone's attention by providing more context, and maybe some references. For example, why would they have the same symmetry?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty lazy and the condition you wrote, namely $D = 2(J+K) = 0$ seems completely wrong. However, let me give you some hints in order to solve this problem. It's easy to convince yourself that the symmetry group of the $q$-state Potts model is $S_q$, the permutation group acting on $q$ objects. To make this completely explicit, take two neighbouring spins, say $s_1$ and $s_2$, and compute their contribution to $H_2$. This will be a $3\times 3$ matrix, depending on the inputs $s_1$ and $s_2$. You'll find that it's a diagonal matrix with entries $\{-J,-J,-J\}$ so it's easy to prove that $S_3$ leaves this matrix invariant. You need to make the argument explicit yourself, since obviously you don't grasp this material properly...

Now consider $H_1$, and again consider two neighboring spins. Again it's a $3 \times 3$ matrix which now depends on the constants $J,K$ and $D$. In Mathematica, this matrix is given by
$$\verb!Table[-J x y - K x^2 y^2 - 
  D/2 (x^2 + y^2), {x, {-1, 0, 1}}, {y, {-1, 0, 1}}]!.$$
You'll have to convince yourself that this makes sense and that my conventions are the same as yours (no guarantuees here). 
WLOG you can assume that $J=1$. Now you want to find the values of $K$ and $D$ such that the above matrix is invariant under any permutation $\sigma \in S_3$. Since this is a homework problem, I won't spell out the details, but it leads to two equations:
$$1 + D + K = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad -1 + D/2 + K = 0.$$
At the locus where these equations intersect, it follows that $S_3$ leaves $H_1$ invariant, at least for a system with two spins.

Comment: Hi

Thank you for your answer and good explanation.  I will try to complete it